# Weak*-topology and probability measures

Tags: probability, general-topology

Let $Y$ denote a separable metric space, and $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ the set of probability (understood as countably additive) measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$. The weak*-topology says that a sequence $\mu_{n}$ (or more generally a net) in $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ converges to $\mu$ when $\int fd\mu_{n}$ converges to $\int fd\mu$ for each bounded continuous mapping $f:Y \to \mathbb{R}$.

My **question** is: It is known that the set $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ is not necessarily closed when endowed with such a topology (see one example [here](http://ubuntuone.com/p/14Z9) where the limit is not countably additive). Is it possible to say more generally that whenever $Y$ is not finite (or perhaps "richer" in some sense) there exists a sequence in $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ weakly* converging to zero? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a sequence of probability measures cannot converge weakly-* to 0.  Consider the bounded continuous function $f=1$.  The weak-* limit must be a measure of total mass 1.